# How to interact with the pre-defined public address

Tags: polkadot-js, substrateinterface

I want to interact with the pre-defined public address. I want to use a map function to hide the public address with any name I want

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Which language, which context and which address?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.